# Maximum likelihood estimators for Gaussian distribution parameters

Tags: statistics

[image]

- Lecture ended before we could cover this section. I have no notes over this section and I am not sure if my work is correct. So far I have,
- Part B:  $$μ = \frac{1}{20}(63+58+...+34+46)=48.35$$ and $$σ=\sqrt{\frac{1}{20}((63-48.35)^2+...+(46-48.35)^2)}= 11.9749$$
- Part C: using the TI-84, normalpdf(45,48.35,11.97) = 0.0320
- Part D: using the TI-84, normalpdf(45, 50, 10) = 0.0352.
- Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: For (a) you need to work out the total area of the histogram (for example the rectangle on the far right has height $5$ and width $10$), and divide the heights by this (so the total area becomes $1$) then look at what corresponds to $45$

Answer (score 1):

The maximum likelihood of the $\sigma$ is $\sqrt{\frac1n \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \hat{\mu})^2} $.

Don't forget to compute the square, average it out and then compute the square root.

The answer of part $(b)$ would affect the other part as well.

Comment: Thank you, that was a typo on my end, it was all supposed to be under a square root and squared.